# Cannot install ATI/AMD FGLRX restricted graphic drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati, ubuntu-restricted-extras

When I try and install the ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphic drivers (post release update) I get an error to read a log file.

Here is the log: http://pastebin.com/RtLNZvXz

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jockey/+bug/873058

But if you want the latest and greatest fglrx follow the instructions on

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI#Manually_installing_Catalyst_12.6